# Load-Testing of Application based on Java Back-end and angular front-end

Tags: apache, performance, benchmarking, load-testing

So I want to load test my application which has a Java-Backend and The Web-pages are served by Angular.
Now, I read about `ab` and how it could be used to test load on my application.
I made a sample `ab Test String` Something like :

> ab -A YWRtaW5Abth2aXMuY29tOmFkbWlu -n 1000 -c 100 http://example.com/

Here From the Documentation I got that:

`-A` is for `base-64 encoded username:password`.

`-c`: ("Concurrency"). Indicates how many `clients (people/users)` will be hitting the site at the same time. While ab runs, there will be -c clients hitting the site. This is what actually decides the amount of stress your site will suffer during the benchmark.

`n`:Indicates how many requests are going to be made. This just decides the length of the benchmark.

**MY Doubts**

1. How Does `ab` test the load, like does it check the load on the front-end or it would also test the load on my java server, since it does page loads.(I am pretty confused here).
2. Do I need to give the login credentials of the server in the `ab` request. Like without credentials to my server how does it enter for each user and then perform multiple page loads for testing
3. Now if i set the variable `-c` to 1000 how do I give multiple base64 Encoded strings of username password.
4. Also, When I have a trial run with and without the auth-key for user the tests run successfully and then result(wrt to time to perform the test) is similar.